# Remove html from only a part of string

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code which should remove all HTML from a part of string, which is quoted by dollar signs (could be more of them). This works fine, but I also need to preserve those dollar signs. Any suggestions, thanks

```
private static String removeMarkupBetweenDollars(String input){
    if ((input.length()-input.replaceAll("\\$","").length())%2!=0)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Missing or extra: dollar");
    }
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$(.*?)\\$",Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    StringBuffer sb =new StringBuffer();

    while(matcher.find())
         { //prepending does NOT work, if sth. is in front of first dollar
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb,matcher.group(1).replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", ""));
        sb.append("$"); //note this manual appending
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Thanks for help!

```
        String input="<p>$<em>something</em>$</p>  <p>anything else</p>";
    String output="<p>$something$</p>  <p>anything else</p>";
```

More complicated input and output:

```
String input="<p>$ bar  <b>foo</b>  bar <span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\">foo</span>  $</p><p>another foos</p> $ foo bar <em>bar</em>$";
String output="<p>$ bar  foo  bar foo  $</p><p>another foos</p> $ foo bar bar$"
```

Comment: HTML matching should not be done with regular expressions.

Comment: Can you provide an input/output example please.

Comment: I, know, but REGEX is the simpliest way to get rid of it. I don't need to do anything else with it...

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve. Please post sample input and expected output - examples speak much loader and clearer than words or code. And delete all your code - there's probably a better way

Comment: Sorry,sample posted, I'm trying to remove all HTML which is inside 2 dollarsigns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some minor tweaks to your code:

```
private static String removeMarkupBetweenDollars(String input) {
    if ((input.length() - input.replaceAll("\\$", "").length()) % 2 != 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Missing or extra: dollar");
    }

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$(.*?)\\$", Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String s = matcher.group().replaceAll("<[^>]+>", "");
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(s));
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String output = input.replaceAll("\\$<.*?>(.*?)<.*?>\\$", "\\$$1\\$");
```

One key point in the regex is the `?` in `.*?` - it means a "non greedy" match, which in turn means "consume the least possible input you can". Without this, the regex would try to consume as much as possible - up to the end of a subsequent occurrence of `$<html>foo</html>$` in the input if one existed.

Here's a test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String input = "<p>$<em>something</em>$</p> <p>and $<em>anything</em>$ else</p>";
    String output = input.replaceAll("\\$<.*?>(.*?)<.*?>\\$", "\\$$1\\$");
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Output:

```
<p>$something$</p> <p>and $anything$ else</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, but what if the input is more complicated? see my edited question?

Comment: This works for a single embedded tag but fails if you have multiple e.g. `"<p>$<em>something</em>$</p>  <p>and $<em>anything</em>$ else</p>"` which returns `"<p>$something</em>$</p>  <p>and $<em>anything$ else</p>"` (wrong).

Comment: @davidpeterson Would you believe I left out a single `?` from the regex. It's fixed now.

Comment: @MartinM I fixed the problem. My group one capture was also greedy - I added an extra `?` to the regex and it works properly now. I also updated the sample test.

Comment: However note that your new input differs from the original in that html no longer comes immediately after the dollar.

Comment: @Bohemian I know, at first, I tried to provide simple example. Guess it was too simple :) HTML may not be first, that's probably why I was scared in writing the code your way-regex is too complicated